# Trying to format a diffForHumans for Laravel Carbon instance

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

Inside my feature test I am trying to add some time specific dates and then I'm trying to get the exact time difference. Currently its rounding to the highest level so in this case months.

Feature Test

```
$title->champions()->attach([$champion1->id => ['champion_from' => Carbon::create(2016, 6), 'champion_to' => Carbon::create(2016, 7, 26)]]);
```

Model

```
public function getLengthOfTitleReignAttribute()
{
    return Carbon::parse($this->pivot->champion_from)->diffForHumans(Carbon::parse($this->pivot->champion_to), true);
}
```

Comment: what is your question?